# Python, How can I dynamically define a variable when it is imported

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't actually know if this is possible but I would like to do the following:

foo.py:

```
# foo.py
my_var = "hello_world"

def fancy(s):
    return s.replace("_"," ").replace("hello", "Hola")
```

main.py:

```
# main.py
from foo import my_var, my_var_fancy

print(my_var)
print(my_var_fancy)
```

And get an output like:

```
>> hello_world
>> Hola world
```

Note that I do not want to explicitly define "my_var_fancy" anywhere. I would like I to be dynamically defined when imported using the fancy function. I suspect this could possibly be accomplished with decorators or something similar to a hasattr() check on the module but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Why do you want this? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info). Any time you want a variable to exist without declaring it, you are doing something wrong.

Comment: How do you think that is going to be used?  Magic names that cannot be traced are an extremely bad idea, in software engineering terms.'

Comment: Similar to the previous point: you generally should avoid doing this. Something like the following is almost always clearer: `from foo import my_var, fancy`, and `print(fancy(my_var))`

Comment: When imported, or when used? I can imagine this idea needlessly defining variables that would never be used, overriding other variables by accident, expected variables being override by accident, etc.

Comment: Never mind the fact that not every variable name of the form `foo_bar` would lead to a valid function call `bar(foo)`.

Comment: I'd like to do this because I have a file with a bunch of predefined variables and while I need to access those in some place, I need to access the fancy version of them in other places. Sure, I could just call `fancy(my_var)` every time I need that version, but seems like a waste of time. Or I could define the variables explicitly as the output of `fancy_my_var = fancy(my_var)` but that just seems like a waste of lines. This is a pretty narrow use case and isn't something wide spread in my code. I can see dictionaries being a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use dictionaries instead of different variable names

```py
def make_fancy(s):
    return s.replace("_"," ").replace("hello", "Hola")

original={
    "my_var": "hello_world",
    "his_var": "Muggins is silly but happy",
    "her_var": "The time is 4 o'clock",
}

fancy = {
    k:make_fancy(v)
    for k,v in original.items()
}

print(fancy)
```

You can now import the `fancy` dictionary into another file and access all of its entries.

#### This avoids the ugliness of dynamic variable names

Dynamic variable names make programs that are very hard to debug.